# R: weighted least squares with errors in x and y

Tags: r

Does anyone know of an existing R function/package for weighted least squares fitting of a straight line where both X and Y have errors (ala York, 1969)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what is called "orthogonal regression", "Deming regression", and other names. Here's one package with a version.

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/MethComp/html/Deming.html

Other links to r-help entries:

http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e9/help/10/02/4669.html